# How to pass String as name for WAV in PlaySound?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Code:

```
PlaySound((wavid.c_str()), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP);
```

Two Errors:

1

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with       parameter of type "LPCWSTR"  The Locksmith   c:\Users\DiMaggio\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\The Locksmith\The Locksmith\CONMAIN.cpp 148
```

2

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'BOOL PlaySoundW(LPCWSTR,HMODULE,DWORD)': cannot convert     argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'    The Locksmith   c:\users\dimaggio\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\the locksmith\the locksmith\conmain.cpp 148
```

Why does this "playSound()" not accept strings as an argument?

Comment: What type is `wavid`?  `std::string`?

Comment: @heavyd Yes. Like I mentioned in the Title, I am trying to use a string for the title. :-)

Comment: @Ruslan Garipov wavid is a string, if variable type is what you're asking.

Comment: If `wavid.c_str()` doesn't help try using `PlaySoundA` instead of `PlaySound` in addition to using `wavid.c_str()`.

Comment: @RuslanGaripov Please refer to EDIT in question. Thank you!

Comment: Use `MultiByteToWideChar`, I don't want to write a sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play sound function signature is:

```
BOOL PlaySound(
   LPCTSTR pszSound,
   HMODULE hmod,
   DWORD   fdwSound
);
```

so you need to pass LPCTSTR as first argument, this resolves to: `const char*` on non UNICODE build, and to `const wchar_t*` on UNICODE one. So because you have some error, you must be on UNICODE build, and you should use `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: How would I cout << a wstring?

Comment: @majneeds2chill use `std::wcout`

Comment: OK. And I'm sorry, I've never worked with wstrings before. I'm trying to read the name of the wav needed from a file, using get and += into wavid. However, wstring doesn't seem to like += because I'm trying to take a regular string and put it in a wstring?

Comment: Is has += but probably you provide wrong argument. You can easily convert std::string to std::wstring using this code : `std::string str("my.wav"); std::wstring wstr(str.begin(), str.end());`. I assume here you dont have any special characters in your file path, which would require conversion to UNICODE.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I'll have to look into wstring to understand what I did a little better, but all of your solutions worked! If you know of any resources (like links) where I can read more about it that would be great. Other than that thank you so much!!!!

Comment: std::string and std::wstring are instantiations of std::basic_string class template, first one uses char as character type, the second one  wchar_t.

Comment: One last question, actually. If I wanted to set wavid as a constant, how would I do so? If I use "quotes" It's considered contant char so how do I do wchar_t?

Comment: that would be `const wchar_t* WAVE_SND = L"my.wav";`

Comment: Sorry I meant as in wavid = ??

Comment: well, thats nearly the same thing, `std::wstring wstr = L"my.wav"`